# What's the difference between ''be going to'' and ''will'' in conditional sentences?

Tags: conditional-constructions, connotations, will-vs-going-to

Please tell me the differences. Do they connote different points?

> 1. You **will** get into trouble if you don't wear your uniform
> 2. You **are going to** get into trouble if you don't wear your uniform

> 1. If they don't accept me I'll **try** to find another school.
> 2. If they don't accept me I'm **going to try** to find another school.

Comment: No, they are basically the same in these sentences. But that is not always the case. There is a small difference here: I'll try to find another school is more an intention and am going to find another school is certain. But: you'll get into trouble and you're going to get into trouble are basically the same. Except that you will get into trouble is a hazy future. Not as definite as you're going to get into trouble. Sorry my answer is somewhat confusing. Will is intention or expresses something that will happen at an unspecified time; going to here in your sentences expresses a certainty.

Comment: Hi, Masih - Have you looked at any reference books or websites about ["will vs. going to"](https://www.google.com/search?q=will+vs+going+to)?   What do you think the differences might be?

Comment: Does [this](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/39850/in-depth-explanation-of-the-difference-between-will-and-going) answer your question adequately? If not, please [edit] and explain why.

Comment: Is this me or has this question been asked [too many times](http://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=Will+be+going+to) in different forms?! :-\