# When to use "will" and when to use "is going to"?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, will-vs-going-to

Sometimes I will see my writing edited by someone, from "will" to "is going to", or vice versa.

Example:

1. Our sheep will give a baby this summer.
2. Our sheep is going to give a baby this summer.

What is the appropriate situation to use "will" versus "is going to"?

Comment: Can you please provide an example sentence or multiple example sentences to help people understand the context in which you're trying to distinguish between the two?

Comment: Both express a future prediction. But *BE+Going to* is normally used when there is a present sign. "It's going to rain( because I can see the dark cloud and lightning)."

Comment: added... maybe I can add more examples if there are different situations

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In depth explanation of the difference between "will" and "going to"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/39850/in-depth-explanation-of-the-difference-between-will-and-going-to)