# ''will'' or ''going to''

Tags: will-vs-going-to

My name is Tom and my friend's name is Anna.

Anna has a plan to go to Croatia in summer(she bought her flight tickets)

if I talk about ***her plans*** , is ''will'' or ''going to '' correct to use in the sentence?(when talking about someone else's plans)

A) Anna will fly to Croatia in summer.

B)Anna is going to fly to Croatia in summer.

if I talk about my planned actions 'going to' is used ,

EX;

I am going to fly to Croatia in summer (not I will.......)

which one (will or going to) is supposed to be used for the context above?

Comment: Why do you think that if the statement is in the first person "will" is not acceptable? Both "will" and "to be going to" can be used for future events: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Going-to_future. Also - not your question - but at least in the U.S., we say "in *the* summer", not "in summer".

Comment: because my flight is a planned action so I can't use ''wil''l in that context.

what is your opinion about the sentences in which someone else's plans mentioned ?

?(sentence a and sentence b)

Comment: I am curious why you think a planned action cannot be expressed with the word "will"? In this context I believe "will" and "to be going to" are equivalent (it also doesn't matter whether you're talking about Anna or yourself).

Comment: This question might have an answer that would help you: [In depth explanation of the difference between “will” and “going to”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/39850/9161) We have more than 50 questions under [tag:will-vs-going-to] that you might want to browse as well.

Answer (score 6):

***Will*** and ***going to*** are both used to indicate future events with a high degree of confidence. They are predictions without caveat. They are stating the future with as much certainty as possible. You can use them for planned actions, yours or others, or predictions of the future; either way, it just means that you are as sure as you can be that it *will* happen.

It can even be used in situations of less confidence, if you add caveats in additional clauses, phrases or sentences.

> I will call you if I remember.

Or in situations where you obviously can't have certainty, but you are expressing the sincerity of your intention.

> I will always find you!

There's no reason you can't use it to talk about plans.