# Does “will” really indicate happened action?

Tags: future-constructions

For example,

I’m going to eat. It means to eat is intended and to eat isn’t needed to happen.

For example,

I’m trying to eat. To eat isn’t needed to happen but is tried.

“Will” means ‘be going to.’ Does it mean action isn’t needed to happen?

It makes sense that **I would eat but I didn’t eat**. And that’s the reason I think so.

Comment: Unless it's a *specific* context where ***will*** is being used primarily so it can be given added stress (to express ***resolute determination*** on the part of the speaker), there's usually no real difference between *I will eat* and *I'm going to eat*.

Comment: ...but I always like to draw attention to [this comment by Peter Shor](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87900/going-to-vs-will#comment176480_87900) about the difference between being warned that an animal ***will bite*** or ***is going to bite***.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In-depth explanation of the difference between "will" and "going to"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/39850/in-depth-explanation-of-the-difference-between-will-and-going-to)

Comment: @FumbleFingers But it makes sense that the flower would bloom yesterday but it didn’t bloom.

Comment: **I would eat but I didn't eat** is meaningless in modern English ('I would eat' used to mean 'I want to eat' ).

Comment: What is your example with will??

Answer (score 0):

No. If you say "I'm going to eat.", you are asserting that you **will** eat. It may turn out that your assertion is *false*, but that is a separate matter unrelated to the content of your assertion. It is different from saying "I'm trying to eat.", in which case you are merely asserting that you are trying "to eat".

Comment: OP is asking about ***will / be going to***, not ***try to***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I already addressed that in my first two sentences. My last sentence was only in case the asker was confused with "trying to eat".

Answer (score 0):

*Will X* means

- X is expected to be true or happen in the future,
- and *will* does not provide information any state of desire, need, correctness, or ability, though ability is implied (generally you will not do something you cannot).

If you want to say "X needs to happen", you likely want to say *must X*.

Understand that *must X* is not synonymous with *need to X* - *must X* really means "X is required" - and that requirement typically comes from logic/deduction (diameter must be 2 x radius, Mary must have been here because she left her jacket), consequences (I must eat to avoid hunger), or authority (you must turn in your report by today).

If none of those apply just use the word "need".  *Must need X* is also possible.

> I would eat but I didn’t eat.

When we get to the word *but*, at that point in the sentence, we already know you didn't eat.  Speaker/listener is expecting the reason why you wouldn't eat after *but*.